# Xamarin.Android DialogFragment some LifeCycle Events not firing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, dialogfragment

I am having an issue working with Xamarin.Android (please see code below)

**MainActivity.cs:**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace DialogFragmentLife
{
    [Activity(Label = "DialogFragmentLife", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Button _btnShowDF;
        private DialogFragmentLife _dfLife;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            _btnShowDF = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnShowDF);
            _btnShowDF.Click += _btnShowDF_Click;
        }

        private void _btnShowDF_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _dfLife = new DialogFragmentLife(this);

            _dfLife.Show(FragmentManager, "dfLife");
        }
    }
}
```

And the **DialogFragmentLife.cs** below

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;

namespace DialogFragmentLife
{
    class DialogFragmentLife : DialogFragment
    {
        private Context _context;

        public DialogFragmentLife(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            RetainInstance = true;

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DialogFragmentLife, container, false);

            return view;
        }

        public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
        {
            base.OnDismiss(dialog);
        }

        public override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }

        public override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }

        public override void OnHiddenChanged(bool hidden)
        {
            base.OnHiddenChanged(hidden);
        }

        public override void OnDestroyView()
        {
            Dialog dialog = Dialog;

            if (dialog != null && RetainInstance)
                dialog.SetDismissMessage(null);

            base.OnDestroyView();
        }

        public override void OnDetach()
        {
            base.OnDetach();
        }

        public override void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
        {
            base.OnCancel(dialog);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, **except** for the DialogFragment's lifecycle events when it is being dismissed, or when the devices are rotated (orientation change), none of the LifeCycle events get fired.

As you can see on the code,

- OnDismiss
- OnPause
- OnStop
- OnHiddenChanged
- OnDestroyView
- OnDetach
- OnCancel

None of them gets fired. I wonder if anyone out there is having this same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more scouring around the net, i manage to get some events fired now by doing the following:

On **MainActivity.cs** i changed

```
using Android.App;
```

to

```
using Android.Support.V7.App;
```

---

Then, on **DialogFragmentLife.cs** i changed

```
using Android.App;
```

to

```
using Android.Support.V4.App;
```

---

Lastly, back on **MainActivity.cs**, instead of showing the DialogFragment by using

```
_dfLife.Show(FragmentManager, "dfLife");
```

i changed it to use the SupportFragmentManager as follows

```
_dfLife.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dfLife");
```

From there on, the OnDestroyView() is now fired when i rotate the screen, also when dismissing the Dialog Fragment

Comment: Also! To retain elements for example a text on EditText, i found out that you need to specify an ID on the element.

Answer (score 1):

**Orientation does not affect dialog fragment lifecycle.**

- DialogFragment does various things to keep the fragment's lifecycle driving it, instead of the Dialog. Note that dialogs are generally autonomous entities -- they are their own window, receiving their own input events, and often deciding on their own when to disappear (by receiving a back key event or the user clicking on a button).
- DialogFragment needs to ensure that what is happening with the Fragment and Dialog states remains consistent. To do this, it watches for dismissing events from the dialog and takes care of removing its own state when they happen. This means you should use Show(FragmentManager, String) or Show(FragmentTransaction, String) to add an instance of DialogFragment to your UI, as these keep track of how DialogFragment should remove itself when the dialog is dismissed.
- Also, know that there are certain lifecycle methods that a dependent on some other method to be called for eg: OnDestroy and OnDestroyView are dependent on Dismiss or closing of the by back button or closing of the fragment in any sense, What you are failing to notice here is that on orientation change the lifecycle events of the activity will be called and not the dialog fragment, One fragment does not affect in any way the lifecycle of the other.
- For information related to working with lifecycles check [this](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-architecture-components-c33b15d89c23) out.This guy has beautifully analyzed every aspect of Android( Activity& Fragment) lifecycle.
- **onActivityCreated**:
  Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving views or restoring state. It is also useful for fragments that use setRetainInstance(boolean) to retain their instance, as this callback tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity instance. This is called after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) and before onViewStateRestored(Bundle).
- **onAttach**: Called when a fragment is first attached to its context. onCreate(Bundle) will be called after this.
- **onCancel**: This method will be invoked when the dialog is cancelled.
- **onCreate**: Called to do the initial creation of a fragment. This is called after onAttach(Activity) and before onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), but is not called if the fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (see setRetainInstance(boolean)).
  Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point. If you want to do work once the activity itself is created, see onActivityCreated(Bundle).
  If your app's targetSdkVersion is M or lower, child fragments being restored from the savedInstanceState are restored after onCreate returns. When targeting N or above and running on an N or newer platform version they are restored by Fragment.onCreate.
- **onCreateDialog**: Override to build your own custom Dialog container. This is typically used to show an AlertDialog instead of a generic Dialog; when doing so, onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) does not need to be implemented since the AlertDialog takes care of its own content.
  This method will be called after onCreate(Bundle) and before onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). The default implementation simply instantiates and returns a Dialog class.
  Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself. To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and onDismiss(DialogInterface).
- **onDestroyView**: Remove dialog.
- **onDetach**: Called when the fragment is no longer attached to its activity. This is called after onDestroy(), except in the cases where the fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (see setRetainInstance(boolean)), in which case it is called after onStop().
- **onDismiss**: This method will be invoked when the dialog is dismissed.
- **onSaveInstanceState**: Called to ask the fragment to save its current dynamic state, so it can later be reconstructed in a new instance of its process is restarted. If a new instance of the fragment later needs to be created, the data you place in the Bundle here will be available in the Bundle given to onCreate(Bundle), onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), and onActivityCreated(Bundle).
  This corresponds to Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and most of the discussion there applies here as well. Note, however: this method may be called at any time before onDestroy(). There are many situations where a fragment may be mostly torn down (such as when placed on the back stack with no UI showing), but its state will not be saved until its owning activity actually needs to save its state.
- **onStart**: Called when the Fragment is visible to the user. This is generally tied to Activity.onStart of the containing Activity's lifecycle.
- **onStop**: Called when the Fragment is no longer started. This is generally tied to Activity.onStop of the containing Activity's lifecycle.

[Referred from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#Lifecycle)

Comment: Thank you, however unfortunately even when i dismiss or cancel or press back button, when the DialogFragment dissapeared, none of the events such as OnDismiss, OnDestroyView, etc mentioned above gets fired

Comment: you should use appcompat that might be one of the reasons as your device might be an old one causing this error, so install support libraries for backward compatibility.

Comment: thanks, i have used the AppCompat and the events gets fired :)